# Is it possible to fetch data from iCloud drive using CloudKit

Tags: icloud, cloudkit, tvos

I want to display user's iCloud drive content in my app which i am building on tvOS . Is it possible to fetch the data on tvOS using cloud kit from iCloud drive.

Answer (score 0):

Not using CloudKit, but yes. Start with "Document-based app" template (optional step, but it provides code snippets for working with documents) and enable `Capabilities`->`iCloud`->`Services`->`iCloud Documents`.

Comment: I want to fetch the image from iCloud drive is there any way we can do that?

Comment: Yes, any kind of document (it is configurable).

Comment: in tvOS document App is not available the right answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65253936/521197